# Intuition behind the scaling property of Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, intuition

I had a course in PDE last year where we used fourier transforms extensively; I understand the rules of manipulation and can prove the scaling theorem directly from the definition using a substitution, but I don't really have any good intuitive argument as to why "compressing" a function causes an expansion of its fourier transform, and vice versa.  I have been trying to gain solid intuition behind the various properties of the fourier transform; but have not gotten far with this one.  If anyone knows of a website / book or a slick argument that covers this; it'd be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What is the scaling theorem?

Comment: @Qiaochu It is usually called the similarity theorem. If $\mathcal{F}(u)$ is the FT of $f(x)$ then $\frac{1}{a}\mathcal{F}\left(\left|\frac{u}{a}\right|\right)$ is the FT of $f(ax)$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Intuitively, One way to think about it is that compressing a sinusoid, increases its frequency.  So compessing a sum of sinusoids will expand the frequency spectrum.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks.  I thought about it a bit and I can see that compressing a signal is equivalent to compressing its component frequencies, which would then cause the frequency spectrum to be spread over a larger range.  Is there a good way to see why the amplitude of each frequency's contribution is the scaled by the reciprocal of the compression factor?

Comment: the amplitude scaling is due to parsevals.   compressing the  signal reduces the energy.