# Scaling property of  Fourier series and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49753/intuition-behind-the-scaling-property-of-fourier-transforms) about the intuition behind the scaling property of the Fourier transform made me wonder about the corresponding notion for a Fourier series.

The Fourier transform of $f(ax)$ is $\frac{1}{|a|} \mathcal{F(\frac{u}{a})}$. If $a>1$ then the graph of $f(ax)$ is $f$ compressed and so its Fourier transform has frequencies that are higher. However they are scaled down in magnitude.

On the other hand take $f(x)= \cos x$. Its fourier series is trivially itself, with the coefficient of $\cos x$ being $1$. Scaling it to $f(ax) = \cos ax$ where $a>1$ is an integer still has a trivial fourier series, and the coefficient of $\cos ax$ is $1$. This is unlike the Fourier transform where the "coefficients" of each frequency get scaled as the formula shows: $\frac{1}{|a|} \mathcal{F(\frac{u}{a})}$.

Is there a conceptual way to explain this discrepancy?

Comment: What discrepancy? If you transform $\cos ax$ you'll get the same effect. The transform *acts on* functions and the series expansion *represents* functions; these are two different concepts. The effect is seen in the former but not the latter because the former by default is a matter of change whereas the latter is by default a matter of identity.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you elaborate in detail.

Answer (score 6):

Since you wanted a conceptual explanation:

the reason is that the action of "scaling" on the circle, and the action of "scaling" on the real line, are two different things.

On the circle, the mapping $\theta \mapsto a\theta$ "wraps around", and for $a$ a nonzero integer, the image of the circle under this map wraps around $|a|$ times.

On the real line, the mapping $x\mapsto ax$ is one-to-one.

And this makes a huge difference.

When you do the rescaling $\cos \theta \to \cos 2\theta$ on the circle, you are not *just* compressing the function by making the characteristic length-scale smaller, you are *also* cramming two copies of the rescaled function into the same circle. In fact, this works for any periodic function: the mapping $g(\theta) \to g(a\theta)$ scales spatially and also makes $|a|$ copies of the function.

When you do the rescaling $f(x) \to f(ax)$ on the real line, you are *only* compressing the function spatially. There still is only one copy of the function. This difference in the number of copies is, morally speaking, why there is a factor of $|a|$ difference in the two formulae.

---

Another way to think about it: a "better" (in some cases) way of thinking about the Fourier series (in the context of as a special case of the Fourier transform; this way is not necessarily better for other applications) is, instead of extending the function on $[0,2\pi]$ periodically, extend it by the $0$ function outside of $[0,2\pi]$. Then you see immediately that the evaluate of the Fourier transform at integer values gives you precisely the Fourier coefficients for the series on the circle. So define the function $g(x) = \cos(x)$ if $x\in [0,2\pi]$ and $0$ elsewhere. The rescaling of $g(x)$ is the function $g(ax) = \cos(ax)$ if $x\in [0,2\pi/a]$ and $0$ elsewhere. This is very different from the function $\cos(ax)$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

This is all to say that what you thought of as rescaling on the circle is not just rescaling: but scaling *and* copying.

Comment: Can you give a link to a source that makes this mathematically precise?

Answer (score 6):

Let $a\neq 0$.  For a function $f$ define $m_af$ by $(m_af)(x) = f(ax)$.  Then the scale factor that appears in a Fourier transform of $m_af$ is directly related to the norm of $m_a$ since $$||m_af||_2 = ||m_a||\cdot ||f||_2$$ and a Fourier transform on $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$ is (up to a normalization factor) unitary.  Now on $\mathbb{R}$ we have $||m_a|| = |a|^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ while on $S^1$ (and $a \in \mathbb{N_{>0}}$) $||m_a||=1$.

As an amusing aside, if you take the Fourier transform of $\cos$ as a tempered distribution then $$\mathcal{F}(m_a\cos) = \tfrac{1}{2|a|}(m_{a^{-1}}\delta_1 + m_{a^{-1}}\delta_{-1})= \tfrac{1}{2|a|}(|a|\delta_a + |a|\delta_{-a}) = \tfrac{1}{2}(\delta_a + \delta_{-a})$$ by the transformation property of the Dirac distribution as noted in a comment.  So in this case there *is* a factor $|a|^{-1}$ as usual although it is not directly visible.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can see what you're getting at -- you want to view the Fourier *series* as a Fourier *transform* that happens to consist of $\delta$ peaks instead of a smoothly varying density, and then you wonder why those $\delta$ peaks don't appear to behave the same under scaling as an ordinary smooth Fourier transform does.

First off, I don't think the default formalism for Fourier transforms actually allows for this viewpoint. It can probably be formalized in *some* way, though, such as by letting the transform produce (or act on?) a [complex measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_measure) instead of an ordinary function. Never mind; let's imagine it can work and see where that leads us.

Now, intuitively it is tempting to think of $C\delta(x-x_0)$ as a "density" that is $0$ everywhere except at $x_0$ where it is $C\cdot\infty$. But that doesn't *really* work -- infinities don't work that way in the first place, and in particular the height of a delta peak *doesn't* behave quite like an infinitary density. And you've chanced upon one of the differences, namely how they react to scaling.

For an ordinary smooth density function $F$ we can scale it by $a$ by using $G(t)=\frac{1}{a} F(\frac{t}{a})$. The inner factor of $\frac{1}{a}$ does the actual stretching of the horizontal axis, and the outer factor of $\frac{1}{a}$ corrects for the resulting area increase, such that
$$\int_{ap}^{aq} G(t)\;dt = \int_{ap}^{aq}\frac1a F(\frac ta)\;dt = \int_p^q F(u)\;du$$
for all intervals $[p,q]$. On the other hand, a delta peak needs no such outer factor, because *at the peak itself* the $\delta$ function cannot see that its argument has been stretched! Instead we have
$$\int_{ap}^{aq} \delta(\frac xa-x_0)\;dx = \int_p^q \delta(x-x_0)\;dx$$
with no outer factor needed to compensate for the horizontal stretching of the peak, because the peak has width 0 and so doesn't stretch at all.

And that is why you're seeing a difference in the behavior of Fourier coefficients versus Fourier transforms.

Comment: I'm not convinced that $\int_{ap}^{aq}\delta(x/a-x_0)dx = \int_{p}^{q}\delta(x-x_0)dx$ is valid. I've seen remarked that $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$, you can't treat the delta function with normal algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @user782220: That's another way of handling the same problem. However, in that case you _cannot_ at the same time treat the coefficient of the delta function as a Fourier coefficient, without correcting for the scaling _then_.

Comment: Let $a\neq 0$ and for $f$ a continuous function let $m_a$ be the functional such that $(m_af)(x) = f(ax)$.  This extends naturally to distributions and then $m_a\delta = |a|^{-1}\delta$.  If not a distribution I'm not sure what your $\delta$ integral signifies.